# Effect of whitespace with complex number definition

Tags: matlab

I understood that whitespace in Matlab expressions was purely cosmetic however I discovered this and I don't understand what's happening. Any ideas?

```
>> [1+i]
 ans =
   1.0000 + 1.0000i
>> [1 +i] 
ans =
   1.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 + 1.0000i   << ????
>> [1 + i]
```

(I'm on 2016a)

EDIT:
Thanks for the responses.

I realise it's easier to see what's happening when looking at non complex numbers:

```
>> [2-1]
ans =
     1
>> [2 - 1]
ans =
     1
>> [2 -1]
ans =
     2    -1
```

But the same parsing rules applied to complex numbers could lead undesired consequences for the unaware.

EDIT 2:
I fully understand the logic of all the above but I'm not sure I'm happy with a mix'n'match approach of whitespace and commas for separators if it can lead to something horrible like this ..

```
> >> [1+2,3+4] ans =
>      3     7
> >> [1 +2,3+4] ans =
>      1     2     7
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first case, as there is not any space around `+` operator, it is resolved as a **binary** operator. Hence, resolved as a complex number.

For the second case, as there is not any space between `+` and `i`, it is resolved as a **unary** operator such as `+1`. From the other hand, space is a separator of matrix element, so in this case detected two elements `+i` and `1`. For the correct case you can write `[1 + +i]` which is equivalent with the third case.

In the third case, because of space around `+` operator, again `+` should be resolved as a **binary** operator. Hence, it would be resolved as a complex number.

Answer (score 3):

Space is not always for the appearance. When one wants to define a matrix, one may use space to separate between the elements of a row. Actually you may use comma `,` or space to separate the two consequent elements.

Example:
`A=[1 2 3; 4 5 6]` will be a `2x3` matrix and is equal to: `[1,2,3;4,5,6];`

In your second case MATLAB considers the `+i` as plus `i`, so as a separate element in the same row.

Comment: Good point that whitespace is a list separator however shouldn't case 3 should then yield the same output as case 2? Surely the parser should either always take the whitepsace as an item separator OR it should resolve for complex numbers first before looking for separators.
To me, what it is doing is not intuitive.

Comment: In case 3 you have the "+" (plus) not right behind "i", but there is a space before and after it. That's why it is considered as a sum and not separately. In case 2, it is like you did emphasize that it is a "+i" and not minus i, so it's simply the its sign.